# Working With Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to compile a regex on python but am having limited success. I am doing the following

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)")
m=pattern.match("gb,&^(@)")
if m: print 1
else: print 2
```

I am expecting the output of the above to print 2, but instead it is printing one. The regex should match strings as follows:

The first letter is alphanumeric or an underscore. All characters after that can be alphanumeric, an underscore, or a dash and there can be 0 or more characters after the first.

I was thinking that this thing should fail as soon as it sees the comma, but it is not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `re.match` does not require a full string match as `matches()` in Java. Add `$` at the end. In Python 3, use `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my problem. Wish I could mark this as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9_])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$")  # when you don't use $ at end it will match only initial string satisfying your regex

m=pattern.match("gb,&^(@)")
if m: 
    print(1)
else: 
    print(2)
pat = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9_])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)")  # this pattern is written by you which matches any string having alphanumeric characters and underscore in starting

if pat.match("_#"):
    print('match')
else:
    print('no match 1')
```

This will also help you understand explaination by @Wiktor with example.